Получение данных с сайта https://pkk.rosreestr.ru/
Стоит задача получения данных с сайта https://pkk.rosreestr.ru/.
Единичные запросы к api по адресу https://pkk.rosreestr.ru/api/features/5?text=искомый кадастровый номерпроходят, но после асинхронной отправки 200 запросов api блокируется.
Как можно обойти данную блокировку? Желательно без регистрации и СМС. Мой вариант с публичными прокси из телеграмма не сработал.
Код:
_headers = {
        'Accept':'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8',
        'Accept-Encoding':'gzip, deflate',
        'Accept-Language':'ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4',
        'Cache-Control':'max-age=0',
        'Connection':'keep-alive',
        'Host':'pkk.rosreestr.ru',
        'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests':'1',
        'X-Compress':'null'
    }

async def get_url_data(ncad: str, session: aiohttp.ClientSession, headers=_headers):
    headers |= {'User-Agent':UserAgent().random}
    proxy = next(itertools.chain(proxies))
    r = await session.get("https://pkk.rosreestr.ru/api/features/5?text="+str(ncad), proxy=f'http://{proxy}', headers=headers, timeout=30, ssl=False)
    data = await r.json()
    return data

